# WSO2IS after upgrading to 5.1.0 SPs is disappering

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

After upgrading wso2is from 5.0.0 to 5.1.0, all my Services Providers disappeared, it's listing in the table SP_APP but the interface don't show the SPs. There any step that I may forgot to execute? I follow the proccess described in wso2 site. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release, with 0 erros. Creating new SPs, work perfect, only old SPs its problem.

Comment: can you check whether the user you are currently logged in has a role like
APPLICATION/<old_sp_name> ?

Comment: There not exist APPLICATION/old_sp_name, only new, create this role. The old SPs only in internal. thank you

Comment: After that I have created role APPLICATION/<old_sp_name>, the old old SPs can be listed by console of IS, but in APIM Store, in **Keys - Production** only show a blank box. But when I create a new application, the box production works fine. Do you know how to fix this? thank you

Comment: What was the command you used to migrate the database? is it "sh wso2server.sh -Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity" or you added "-DmigrateIdentity" also? In the latter case, you can expect this.

Comment: I used this command sh wso2server.sh -Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity

Comment: Looking the migration client code, apparently the migration tool do not run this migrateIdentityData or even migrateIdentityDBFinalize, the migration tool simple ignore these methods.

Comment: If you use -Dmigrate parameter, it will run both methods you have mentioned, refer databaseMigration() method of the migration client.

Comment: Yes I know, but looking deep the migration client, my database schema is different that expected by migrateIdentityData method, my table IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN do not have the TOKEN_ID column, and I have installed the WSO2ISSP1. Why the migrateIdentityData try to update this column?

Comment: TOKEN_ID column does not exist in 5.0.0. It is added from the migration client. Please enable the debug logs for org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.client package and run the migration again on a new database dump