# Identity server migration from 5.0.0 to 5.1.0 failing

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have attempted to migrate our HA configuration of Identity Server from 5.0.0 to 5.1.0 and after the migration my SAML based Service Providers fail.

Users attempting to authenticate for a SAML based SP see
"A Service Provider with the Issuer 'reallyGreatSAMLService' is not registered".

When I attempt to view the SAML configuration in the SP’s setting page, the SAML settings are missing.

When I use the Registry Browser, all SAML entries are missing.

Any suggestion where in my data I should start looking to solve this problem?

This appears to be similar to [WSO2IS after upgrading to 5.1.0 SPs is disappering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010700/wso2is-after-upgrading-to-5-1-0-sps-is-disappering) other than it doesn’t explicitly mention SAML.

Thanks,
…pat

Comment: I should have added that my CAS based Service Providers were successfully migrated and continued to work.  I only have SAML and CAS Service Providers so I cannot comment on any of the other types.  ...pat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the process I was given to create the new EIS HOME failed to copy the configuration changes for the remote registry.

The migration was looking for '/_system/config/repository/identity/SAMLSSO'
My system was configured for '/_system/asNodes/repository/identity/SAMLSSO'

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances/#DS_Strategy_B

In repository/conf/registry.xml I changed the configuration as follows -

```
    <mount overwrite="true" path="/_system/config">
            <instanceId>instanceid</instanceId>
            <!--targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath-->
            <targetPath>/_system/asNodes</targetPath>
    </mount>
```

...pat